# How to get this UI effect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have been given a mockup screen and we already have ,css files and bootstrap classes in this codebase. I was just wondering what classes to use to get these two effects? The word new is in it's own white box and getting the text OR in the middle of an HR tag.

[image: Text]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Nisharg. I will try to post what I tried on Monday. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**In HTML:**

```
<div class='hr-or'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.hr-or {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  text-align: center;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

div.hr-or:before {
  content: 'OR';
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, Ashok! I shall try it out and will mark the answer. Appreciate your reply.

Comment: Sorry @AShok. This is still an open item for me here. I am waiting for the new twitter bootstrap classes. I *will* respond to this once I get it. I tried the above solution and it is looking great for now. I will mark it as an answer if we decide to go this route. Thanks again!